# Using JavaScript this.target to open a jQuery window but prevent (2nd) new blank window opening?

Tags: javascript, window

I'm using this JavaScript to open a jQuery window when a user clicks the submit button on a login form in HTML.

The thing is I'm using 'this.target' to currently get a jQuery window to open up, so it looks like a little dialogue box that says "please wait while we log you in."

The problem I have is the script seems to require `this.target = 'shadowbox'` to function properly, however that same piece of code is causing a second blank window to open up and I don't want this to happen.

I have tried using prevent default function and this solves the problem I have but this also prevents the user from logging in so is there a way I can get this 2nd blank window to not open?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<iframe src="loginin.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
        player:     "html",
        height:     300,
        width:      500
    });

        this.target = 'shadowbox' 




    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why not use a jquery dialog ( to inform the user ) from jQuery-UI?

Comment: only because i wanted to add a gif loading image to the page. would i still be able to do this in dialogue?

Comment: you just want a loader to show on the page? try these:
http://demos.mimiz.fr/jquery/loader

A jQuery dialog is like any piece of html, you only need to load the message and maybe that loader gif into it (as an image) and you should be goo to go

Comment: ok thanks i've had a look at that, so how would i structure the javascript for launching when the user clicks submit button, i have tried this but it won't load the dialogue box:        <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {  
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $.loader({
        className:"blue-with-image",
        content:''
    });
});
   
  
 
   
    });
</script>

Comment: you could access the submit button element directly:
`$( '#submitBtnId' ).off( 'click' ).on( 'click', function(){
    $.loader({ className:"blue-with-image", content:'' });
});`